# How to conditionally subtract row values in r

Tags: r

In the example data below, I'd like to find the difference in values for each Parent based on Transplant and then divide by the average of all values in that column. Specifically, what is the difference in BM for Parent 21 between Outer Lagoon and Inner Lagoon in the Transplant column divided by the average of all BM values (BM @ Outer Lagoon - BM @ Inner Lagoon)/mean(BM)? And then how do I apply this to each of the last 7 columns (BM, BWx.d...)?

```
df <- structure(list(Parent = c(21L, 21L, 22L, 22L), Transplant = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Inner Lagoon", "Outer Lagoon"), class = "factor"), Origin = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Inner Lagoon", "Outer Lagoon"), class = "factor"), Timepoint = c(3, 
3, 3, 3), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("MCAP", "PCOM"), class =. 
"factor"), BM = c(5.865888296, 7.181633357, 6.366555079, 6.413772163), BWx.d = 
c(0.539910592, 0.670790028, 0.60117695, 0.663487904), LE = c(0.009864166, 0.007034995, 
0.010088708, 0.008510985), GPSA = c(0.017825905, 0.037349997, 0.020185893, 0.033437065), RSA 
= c(0.005100527, 0.007212994, 0.005893039, 0.011174223), P_RSA = c(3.616330774, 5.516517387, 
3.590072155, 2.994321812), Survival = c(91.89189189, 100, 100, 97.2972973)), row.names = 
81:84, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why don't you try writing some code yourself first?

Comment: Something is wrong with the data you've put up; I can't reproduce it. Please check

Comment: My mistake - the code I had before had a typo. This should work -  I have this running abs(df$BM[df$Transplant == "Outer Lagoon"] - df$BM[df$Transplant == "Inner Lagoon"])/mean(df$BM), but I can't figure out how to apply it across columns

Comment: The `dput` which you have shared is giving errors. We can't use it. Can you check that?

Comment: An approach with `lead` function could work too I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `.` in the class definition for `Species` in the df which causes a problem. Once removed this works fine.
This is an interesting problem as you need values from alternate rows (`df$Transplant == "Outer Lagoon"` and `df$Transplant == "Inner Lagoon"`) and from all rows (`mean(BM)`) in your calculation. So simple grouping by `Transplant` will not work.
My thought is to create a wide data frame using `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` using the `Transplant` column for pivotting. This will create additional value columns for each unique value of `Transplant`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

meanBM <- mean(df$BM)

df <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Transplant,
              values_from = c("BM", "BWx.d", "LE", "GPSA", "RSA", "P_RSA", "Survival")
              )
```

We also need to calculate the mean of `BM` for all rows so we need to do that prior to pivotting. With this result:

```
> glimpse(df)
Observations: 2
Variables: 18
$ Parent                  <int> 21, 22
$ Origin                  <fct> Outer Lagoon, Outer Lagoon
$ Timepoint               <dbl> 3, 3
$ Species                 <fct> MCAP, MCAP
$ `BM_Inner Lagoon`       <dbl> 5.865888, 6.366555
$ `BM_Outer Lagoon`       <dbl> 7.181633, 6.413772
$ `BWx.d_Inner Lagoon`    <dbl> 0.5399106, 0.6011770
$ `BWx.d_Outer Lagoon`    <dbl> 0.6707900, 0.6634879
$ `LE_Inner Lagoon`       <dbl> 0.009864166, 0.010088708
$ `LE_Outer Lagoon`       <dbl> 0.007034995, 0.008510985
$ `GPSA_Inner Lagoon`     <dbl> 0.01782590, 0.02018589
$ `GPSA_Outer Lagoon`     <dbl> 0.03735000, 0.03343707
$ `RSA_Inner Lagoon`      <dbl> 0.005100527, 0.005893039
$ `RSA_Outer Lagoon`      <dbl> 0.007212994, 0.011174223
$ `P_RSA_Inner Lagoon`    <dbl> 3.616331, 3.590072
$ `P_RSA_Outer Lagoon`    <dbl> 5.516517, 2.994322
$ `Survival_Inner Lagoon` <dbl> 91.89189, 100.00000
$ `Survival_Outer Lagoon` <dbl> 100.0000, 97.2973
```

The subsequent calculations become easy now as we can do them by row: the values for `BM` to `Survival` are now in one and the same row.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(new_col = abs(`BM_Outer Lagoon` - `BM_Inner Lagoon`)/meanBM)
```

with:

```
> df$new_col
[1] 0.203771528 0.007312585
```

Which is the same result as you have calculated. You can easily expand this for other columns.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.